# Best place to put third-party DLLs for referencing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, reference

I'm working on a project that is stored in SVN. The project has a dependency on a third-party DLL, so it will need to have a reference to that DLL.

Where is the best place to store this DLL so that anyone who opens the project from SVN can compile it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Usually I create a `lib` subfolder to the root and place all third-party assemblies there. Then all the projects reference the assemblies from this location. That way the project is self-contained and the third-party assemblies are versioned along with the source code.

Comment: You are adding them under a solution folder?

Comment: Yes I do and they are checked-in along with the source code. You can consider them as source code required to make your project work, it's just that you don't have the source :-) This way any developer can fetch the source of the project from and not ask why it doesn't compile because it can't find some third party DLLs. Here's an example of an [example ASP.NET MVC project](https://github.com/darind/samplemvc) I wrote which illustrates the concept.